# Can we cache a JAX-RS Jersey Response for sending it multiple times?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have to send the same `Response` over and over, like:

```
 private Response abortWithUnauthorized() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE,
                           AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " realm=\"" + REALM + "\"")
                       .build();
}
```

Can I save this `Response` in a static field once and then only return it later, every time I need to send a 401 Response?

Comment: Use a utility class and method.

Comment: Why not? There is nothing in this `Response` that would forbid to make it `static final`.

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't know, that's why I am asking, maybe there was some inner state of the `Response` being set after it's sent back, I am not familiar with the source-code, so I rather not assume things

Comment: @PaulSamsotha you mean some other utility class and specific method or this one I posted is fine?